# Watir-webdriver Ajax response

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Experiencing a problem when running watir-web driver to test Ajax responses from our site. The site is designed to contain a list of items. When a new item is added the site will submit the entry via Ajax and wait for a response to tell the site to display this new entry. We are finding these Ajax responses are coming back blank whilst running the page via watir in both chrome and Firefox. However when trying the scenario out side of watir the Ajax responses contain data. 
My question is are we over looking something when setting up our browsers? 
Additional info using latest versions of gems but testing on Ubuntu 12.04.

here is the code to set-up the two browsers:

```
download_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}/Results"  #download location (FF only)

        profileFF = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
        profileFF['browser.download.folderList'] = 2 # custom location
        profileFF['browser.download.dir'] = download_directory
        profileFF['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/msword" #auto save rulw

        c = Watir::Browser.new :chrome 
        f = Watir::Browser.new :firefox  ,:profile => profileFF
```

Comment: A code snippet would be useful, as well as more details about the server side: is the item added correctly, or is there an error condition?

Comment: The item gets added correctly, if you were to refresh the page it will display the newly added item. However the response of the Ajax is meant to contain the details of the newly added item to be added to the list.

Comment: Can you provide link to the site, if it is public? Or to a similar page if it is not public?

Comment: How are you checking the ajax responses?

Comment: @anonygoose firebug/google chrome dev tools. Network tab.

Comment: So are you getting an empty ajax response (but something that actually shows up in the net tab) or no response in the net tab at all?

Comment: @anonygoose we get something back but has no content.